# iOS App Suggesting Edits Not Allowed

Tags: bug, ios-app

[image: Suggested edits forbidden]

I'm testing out the iOS app for SE and I like it so far (in fact, I'm posting this from it), but I believe I've found a bug of some sort: I'm not allowed to edit posts. I can click on the edit link, but as soon as I press "preview" an error comes up suggesting that I don't have the reputation to do this.

I have 166 reputation on SO (which is where I tried to perform the edit), which allows me to suggest edits (and works fine on a desktop PC) but I can't do it on my iPhone 5.

Is this a bug? Or has something changed recently that I've missed?

Comment: @psubsee2003 Ah, I thought I was posting on Meta — evidently not, my mistake. Thanks for the link too.

Comment: You're on Meta.StackOverflow.  As of 2 weeks ago, it is a different site than Meta.StackExchange.  You aren't the first and won;t be the last to make the mistake